# salt-call output occurs npm debug info

Tags: npm, salt-stack

#### salt-call output occurs npm debug info

when I execute commands on a minion  `salt-call sys.list_modules --output=json` , 
the output is:

```
[INFO    ] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
{
    "local": [
        "acl", 
        "aliases", 
        "alternatives", 
        "apache", 
        "archive", 
         ...
        "user", 
        "vbox_guest", 
        "virtualenv", 
        "webutil", 
        "xfs"
    ]
}
```

I don't know why it contains this:

`[INFO    ] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'`

#### Minion Log

```
tail -f /var/log/salt/minion

2016-11-29 18:04:37,669 [salt.modules.cmdmod][INFO    ][2598] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
2016-11-29 18:05:33,742 [salt.modules.cmdmod][INFO    ][2804] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
2016-11-29 18:06:15,550 [salt.modules.cmdmod][INFO    ][2946] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
2016-11-29 18:07:28,020 [salt.modules.cmdmod][INFO    ][3053] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
2016-11-29 18:07:56,166 [salt.modules.cmdmod][INFO    ][3102] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
2016-11-29 18:08:59,328 [salt.modules.cmdmod][INFO    ][3238] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
2016-11-29 18:09:41,690 [salt.modules.cmdmod][INFO    ][3312] Executing command 'npm --version' in directory '/root'
```

#### Salt-Version

> salt-minion 2016.3.1 (Boron)

#### npm --version

> 1.3.6